# How can I add back Documents and Music to my folder bookmarks?

Tags: nautilus, directory, home-directory, bookmarks

I deleted my Music and Documents folder. Now after recreating these, I don't know how to add them back to the bookmarks pane shown below.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add them back you have to edit the file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` and add them back in, this is the file how it looks on my system as i have changed the names all to be different and lower case:

```
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/share"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/doc"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/"
```

You can edit this with *gedit* via the GUI or with your prefered text editor in terminal. If the file keeps changing back make it read only to prevent the system from changing it.